# rdp web client of virtualbox

Tags: webclient, virtualbox, rdp

thank you for reading my question.
I want to login the virtual machine romotely through rdpweb shipped with virtualbox sdk.Of course, the virtual machine was installed in the virtualbox.The rdpweb(a folder) contains 4 files, webclient3.html, swfobject.js, webclient.js and RDPClientUI.swf.
Firstly, I copy rdpweb to the /.../tomcat/webapp. So i can visit webclinet3.html now. And there is a image which shows what i get.Sorry, i haven't enough reputation for posting a image.I just can put a link to the image.

http://i.minus.com/jbdHDzjWwQntWQ.PNG

An error happened. Google says that putting the crossdomin.xml to the root of webapp would solve the bug.The bug may be aroused by flash.But it is invalid for me. Why ?
My physical host is win7(ip:192.168.1.107), and my virtual guest is windowsxp(ip:192.168.1.111). The version of the virtualbox is 4.1.8.
Any help would be appreciated!Thank you very much.
I am so sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Your configuration looks like you have configured your WinXP guest with a bridged network adapter, and you are trying to connect directly to it. Have you enabled Remote Desktop on the WinXP guest? Go to the Control Panel -> System applet, then choose the remote tab and be sure to check both boxes to allow remote desktop connections. You will also need to make sure the firewall will allow this connection to the guest.

[image: System Control Panel Applet for Windows XP - Remote tab]

VirtualBox also have the capability to serve up a virtual machines display over RDP or VNC (VNC in the OSE - Open Source Edition). If you are wanting to use that capability then you should be connecting to the HOST IP address - not the guest. Since your host is Windows 7 you will also need to adjust the Remote Display Server Port for your guest (in the VM Settings in VirtualBox) to use a port besides 3389. I usually pick 3390. Your screenshot doesn't show somewhere you can enter the TCP port, so this approach may not be supported, but you could try appending :3390 to the IP address.

[image: VirtualBox Virtual Machine Settings - Display Section, Remote Display Tab]

**Original Answer:**

Could you post the crossdomain.xml file you are currently using? This is almost certainly a problem with it.

My guess is that your crossdomain.xml file should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- http://127.0.0.1:8080/crossdomain.xml -->
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="192.168.1.111" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

You could start with just putting `*` instead of the IP address in the file as well - though that is generally not recommended as it opens the possibility that the flash player can access any resource on any network. It would make it easier to access other virtual machines you might use in the future with different addresses.

Comment: I have been tried the method you said.But it didn't work. OK, I will post the crossdomain.xml file when i go home(Now i am in the company).Thank you for replying.

Comment: hello, my crossdomain.xml is below:                               <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain=" * " to-ports="80-9000" />
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain=" * " headers=" * "/>
</cross-domain-policy>